# Can SharePoint Search Work with Anonymous Access?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint

I've been setting up a site for full anonymous access but was getting prompted for a login when using SharePoint search (right when I hit the search button before getting results).  Is there something I'm missing in setting up SharePoint search for anonymous access?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint definitely does support anonymous. There are settings in both IIS and SharePoint that need to be changed. Check out this blog entry for details:
http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2006/09/25/Enabling-anonymous-access-in-SharePoint-2007.aspx

Also, here is another article specifically related to getting search working:
http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/max/archive/2008/02/20/sharepoint-search-and-anonymous-users.aspx

Comment: Negatory, the SITE is setup for anonymous access just fine, search did not work, read the question...

Comment: I updated my answer with another link to an article specifically about search.

Comment: Well, Serverfault won't allow me to undo my negative vote (sorry) but since you ARE now the answer, so CONGRATS, you'll probably be one of the few who got marked negative by the questioner, then marked as the answer. :-D

Comment: Isn't there a badge for that? :)

Comment: Marked up 'cuz there should be, I'll call it the "apologist" badge...